# Longitudinal Cluster Analysis

Tags: clustering, panel-data

I have data with subjects, 4 observations each, ordered by time (4 time points each). And, I have some additional numerical variables. I want to perform a cluster analysis to see if there are any clusters in the data. I know how to do it with no longitudinal data (for example, k nearest neighbors - can be easily done with any statistical package), but I do not know how to do it with longitudinal data. Can you please advice me on the matter? I am using SPSS, R or JMP, any will do. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify? I have understood that you have $N$ subjects described by 4 points at each time $t$, over some period of length $T$, thus your dataset has the format $N \times 4 \times T$. Is that right?

Comment: No, I have N subjects, each has 4 lines in the file, each line represents a different time point (1<=t<=4). In addition, in each line each subject has P variables. So my data set is N*P*4. The time points are the same for all subjects (1 month, 3 months, 1 year, 5 years).

Comment: K-means is not a statistical measure; it does not care if the data is longitudinal or not. You can just apply it. You might consider standardizing within a subject so that you focus more on the trends or patterns than magnitudes.

Comment: k nearest neighbors is a classifier, not a clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you always have the same time points for every instance, you should be able to just treat this as a p*4 dimensional vector space.

It would be much harder if the series would vary in length and alignment.

Comment: so what you (and the others that commented) say, is that I can just to cluster analysis with all variables and all observations together, treating the time as just another variable ? by the way, a non-related question, can cluster analysis handle correlated variables ?